# css transition effect for divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've the below Code.

```js
function showOrHideDiv() {
   var e = document.getElementById('pageRightMenu');
   var l = document.getElementById('pageLeftMenu');
   if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    l.style.width = '99%';
    l.style.transition = "all 2s";       // Standard syntax
    l.style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s"
   }
   else {
    l.style.width = '60%';
    l.style.transition = "width 2s";       // Standard syntax
    l.style.WebkitTransition = "width 2s";
    e.style.display = 'block';

   }
  }
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blended_grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Webkit 35: */
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  /* Firefox 28, Opera 22, IE 11: */
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
}

.pageHeader {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pageLeftMenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pageRightMenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: right;
  clear: none;
  height: 80%;
  width: 39%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
  <div class="pageLeftMenu" id="pageLeftMenu">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick="showOrHideDiv()" />
  </div>
  <div class="pageRightMenu" id="pageRightMenu" style="display: none">
    This a textF
  </div>
</div>
```

Here as part of my requirements, I've created 2 divs, and in left div there is a button, when I click, the other div will either appear or disappear, and everything is fine, but I want to have a css transition effect when I hide or show the div.

**Update:**

I'm able to do the transition. I've tried a js function that is doing what I actually require (updated in this question), but when you show the 2nd div, the div appears first below and then beside the other div. How can I fix it, I mean, after the entire transition, the 2nd div should be visible

please run the code snippet to get a better understanding of my issue.

please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Use CSS3 [Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: If you want to have a transition affect, you must have the `display` value change at the end of the animation since that is a value that cannot be animated. This solution would require additional javascript, I believe. If you do not need the space from the div, you can animate `opacity` values.

Comment: @Pytth, Can you please help me with it? I'm not a designer, trying out my hand on this side.

Comment: @Pytth , can you please look at my updated code?

Comment: @Fuross, can you please look at my updated code?

Comment: With the current code the best solution I can recommend for you is to use the `setTimeout()` method. In your 
"else" change `e.style.display = 'block'` to `setTimeout(function(){ e.style.display = 'block' }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the jQuery `fadeOut()` function, which animates the opacity to zero and then sets the "display" property to "none" when the animation is finished:

```
function showOrHideDiv() {
   var $e = $(document.getElementById('pageRightMenu'));
   var l = document.getElementById('pageLeftMenu');
   if ( $e.is(":visible") ) {  //safer comparison in case you change things later
      l.style.width = '100%';
      $e.fadeOut(500);   //fade out, taking 500ms
   } else {
      l.style.width = '60%';
      $e.fadeIn(500);    //fade in, taking 500ms
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I've tried a js function that is doing what I actually require, but when you show the 2nd div, the div appears first below and then beside the other div. How can I fix it, I mean, after the entire transition, the 2nd div should be visible

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

- Make this containing element a **flexbox** using `display: flex`
- Give the `pageLeftMenu` a "fixed" width using `flex: 0 0 auto`, which means the width will be taken from the `width` property (and therefore animated)
- Give the `pageRightMenu` a "flexible" width using `flex: 1 1 0`, which means it will take up all the remaining space in the parent not used by `pageLeftMenu`.

The example below shows the effect. Check out this guide for more on flexbox: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

```js
function showOrHideDiv() {
   var e = document.getElementById('pageRightMenu');
   var l = document.getElementById('pageLeftMenu');
   if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
    l.style.width = '99%';
    l.style.transition = "all 2s";       // Standard syntax
    l.style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s"
   }
   else {
    l.style.width = '60%';
    l.style.transition = "width 2s";       // Standard syntax
    l.style.WebkitTransition = "width 2s";
    e.style.display = 'block';

   }
  }
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blended_grid {
  display: flex;    //instead of display: block
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Webkit 35: */
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  /* Firefox 28, Opera 22, IE 11: */
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  
}

.pageHeader {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pageLeftMenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;    //use the width property to determine width
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pageRightMenu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  float: right;
  clear: none;
  height: 80%;  
  flex: 1 1 0;       //use up all remaining space
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blended_grid">
  <div class="pageLeftMenu" id="pageLeftMenu">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onClick="showOrHideDiv()" />
  </div>
  <div class="pageRightMenu" id="pageRightMenu" style="display: none">
    This a textF
  </div>
</div>
```